# Karp-Rabin with bitwise hash

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, search, rags-to-riches

As a Rags-to-Riches re-implementation of the Karp-Rabin question [here, **from @tsleyson**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70066/java-karp-rabin-string-matching-part-2), I thought it would be interesting to understand the algorithm better, and to use bitwise-shifting instead of prime multiplication, to compute the rolling hash.

[Karp-Rabin is a text-search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) that computes a rolling hash of the current text, and only if the rolling hash matches the search term's hash, does it double-check that the search actually matches. Because the hash is computed in \$O(1)\$ time for each advance through the text, it is essentially an \$O(n)\$ search algorithm with an additional \$O(m)\$ confirmation check for each potential match that is found. The best case is \$O(n)\$ for no matches, and worst case is \$O(nm)\$ if everything matches (for example, searching for "aa" in "aaaaaaaaaaaaa").

The description for the algorithm suggests using a 'base' prime number as the foundation for a hashing algorithm that allows you to 'rotate' an out-of-scope character off of the hash, and then add a new member to it. As you 'roll' the hash down the search text, if the hash matches the hash of your pattern, you can then double-check to see if it is just a collision, or a real match.

Instead of using a system requiring repeated multiplications by prime numbers, I decided to use a computationally simpler bit-shifting algorithm (though the logic may be more complicated, the computations should be simpler). In essence, the algorithm I use uses a long value (64-bit) as a hash, and it rotates characters on to the hash, and uses XOR bitwise logic to 'add' or 'remove' the characters.

I am looking for a review of the usability, and any performance suggestions.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class KarpRabin {

    private static final int[] EMPTY = new int[0];

    // Use a prime number as the shift, which means it takes a while to reuse
    // bit positions in the hash. Creates a good hash distribution in the
    // long bit mask.
    private static final int SHIFT = 31;
    // bits in the long hash value
    private static final int BITS = 64; 

    private final char[] patternChars, textChars;
    private final long patternHash;
    private final int size;
    private final int endPosition;
    private final int tailLeftShift, tailRightShift;

    private long textHash = 0L;
    private int pos = 0;

    /*
     * Private constructor, only accessible from public static entry methods.
     */
    private KarpRabin(String pattern, String text) {
        // inputs pre-validated.
        // inputs not null, not empty, and pattern is shorter than text.
        patternChars = pattern.toCharArray();
        textChars = text.toCharArray();
        size = this.patternChars.length;
        endPosition = this.textChars.length - size;

        // calculate the bit-shifts needed to remove the tail of the search
        // since the hash values are 'rotated' each time, we can count the
        // rotations that will be needed (size - 1) before a char is at the
        // tail, and that will be the relative left/right shifts needed.
        // note that left and right shifts perform a 'rotation' when combined,
        // essentially rotating the character by tailLeft bits to the left.
        tailLeftShift = ((size - 1) * SHIFT) % BITS;
        tailRightShift = BITS - tailLeftShift;

        // Compute the hash of the pattern
        // use a temp variable ph because patternHash is final
        long ph = 0L;
        for (char c : this.patternChars) {
            ph = addHash(ph, c);
        }
        patternHash = ph;

        // seed the hash for the first X chars in the text to search.
        textHash = 0L;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            textHash = addHash(textHash, this.textChars[i]);
        }

        // advance the search to the first 'hit' (if there is one).
        // check to make sure we are not already at a match first.
        if (textHash != patternHash || !confirmed()) {
            advance();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Shift the existing hash, and XOR in the new char.
     */
    private final long addHash(long base, char c) {
        return (base << SHIFT | base >>> (BITS - SHIFT)) ^ c;
    }

    /*
     * Shift the char to remove to the place it would be at the tail, and XOR it
     * off.
     */
    private final long removeHash(long base, char c) {
        long ch = c;
        // this is essentially a rotation in a 64-bit space.
        ch = ch << tailLeftShift | ch >>> tailRightShift;
        return base ^ ch;
    }

    /*
     * Return the next match, and advance the search if needed.
     */
    private int next() {
        if (pos > endPosition) {
            return -1;
        }
        int ret = pos;
        advance();
        return ret;
    }

    /*
     * move the position to the next 'hit', or the end of the search text.
     */
    private void advance() {
        while (++pos <= endPosition) {
            // remove the tail char from the hash
            textHash = removeHash(textHash, textChars[pos - 1]);
            // add in the new head char
            textHash = addHash(textHash, textChars[pos + size - 1]);
            // check to see if we have a match.
            if (textHash == patternHash && confirmed()) {
                return;
            }
        }

    }

    /*
     * Double-check a hash-hit. Assumes the hash computes are equal.
     */
    private boolean confirmed() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (patternChars[i] != textChars[pos + i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Identify whether the pattern appears in the given text.
     * <p>
     * Null input values will return false, and an empty-string pattern will
     * return true (the empty string is a match in any other non-null string)
     * 
     * @param pattern
     *            the pattern to search for
     * @param text
     *            the text to search in
     * @return true if the pattern exists in the text.
     */
    public static boolean match(final String pattern, final String text) {
        if (pattern == null || text == null || pattern.length() > text.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (pattern.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }

        KarpRabin kr = new KarpRabin(pattern, text);
        return kr.next() >= 0;
    }

    /**
     * Identify all locations where the pattern exists in the search text.
     * <p>
     * Null input values will result in no matches, and the empty search pattern
     * will be located at all positions in the search text.
     * 
     * @param pattern
     *            the pattern to search for
     * @param text
     *            the text to search in
     * @return the integer positions of each found occurrence. An empty array
     *         will be returned if there are no matches.
     */
    public static int[] allMatches(String pattern, String text) {
        if (pattern == null || text == null || pattern.length() > text.length()) {
            return EMPTY;
        }
        if (pattern.isEmpty()) {
            // empty string is found everywhere
            int[] ret = new int[text.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
                ret[i] = i;
            }
            return ret;
        }

        KarpRabin kr = new KarpRabin(pattern, text);
        // guess the size first, and expand/trim it as needed.
        int[] possibles = new int[text.length() / pattern.length()];
        int count = 0;
        int pos = 0;
        while ((pos = kr.next()) >= 0) {
            if (count >= possibles.length) {
                // expand the matches (a lot). This indicates overlapping results.
                // which is unusual.
                possibles = Arrays.copyOf(possibles, possibles.length * 2 + 2);
            }
            possibles[count] = pos;
            count++;
        }
        // trim the matches.
        return Arrays.copyOf(possibles, count);
    }
}
```

I have been testing it against some input data similar to @tsleyson's, and then added in a performance test too, that checks the scalability of a non-matching case.

```
private static final void scalabilityTests() {
    String input = "abcdefghijklmnopquestuvwxyz";
    long[] times = new long[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        long nanos = System.nanoTime();
        for (int j = 0; j < 5000; j++) {
            sum += allMatches("abcdefghx", input).length;
        }
        times[i] = sum + System.nanoTime() - nanos;
        // double the times....
        input += input;
    }
    System.out.println("Scalability (should double each time): " + Arrays.toString(times));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] inputs = { "", null, "abr", "abra", "abrabrabra", 
                        "abracadabrabracadabra", "cabrac", "cabracadabrabracadabrac",
                        "abbbbrrraaabbbccrrabbba" };
    for (String inp : inputs) {
        int[] matches = allMatches("abra", inp);
        System.out.printf("Matches %s %s at %s%n", inp, match("abra", inp), Arrays.toString(matches));
    }
    // run three times for warmups....
    scalabilityTests();
    scalabilityTests();
    scalabilityTests();
}
```

Comment: Given my ignorance of bit twiddling, this is way beyond my ability to review, but it's cool; +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> to use bitwise-shifting instead of prime multiplication, to compute the rolling hash.

This is an optimization, I'm not sure about. It's a bit faster (1 instead of 3 or 4 cycles latency, but probably the same throughput on modern Intel), but the hash quality is worse.

This assumes the use of rotations optimized by the JIT, which is not the case for the reviewed code. It's quite possible that a hand-made rotation is worse than multiplication.

You need no prime, any odd number would do.

---

```
// Use a prime number as the shift, which means it takes a while to reuse
// bit positions in the hash. Creates a good hash distribution in the
// long bit mask.
private static final int SHIFT = 31;
```

For `int`, the rotation distance of 31 would be equivalent to -1, which is not good as the next `char` uses about the same bits. For `long`, it's not bad.

You're speaking about primes, but the shift is modulo 64 and there's no such thing as primes in the ring `Z/64`. Again, what you need is a number co-prime to 64, i.e., odd. This assures that it takes 64 operations to land in the same position.

I don't think 31 is very good, as after two operations, you get 62, i.e., -2. So using three ASCII chars, a collision can be easily produced as their bits overlap.

When sticking with ASCII, 7 should be fine, but for general strings, I'd suggest at least 16. FWIW, with 17, you're guaranteed that there'll no collisions for up 3 steps. After 4 steps, it totals to 68, i.e., 4, which is not perfect, so I'd go for 19 instead. A measurement with real data could tell us more, while I guess, the answer is that it doesn't matter much.

---

```
(base << SHIFT | base >>> (BITS - SHIFT))
```

Wrong! Use `Long.rotateLeft`. It does exactly the same, but is clearer and much faster as it's an intrinsic. Whenever the JIT sees `Long.rotateLeft`, it uses the rotation instruction; when it sees an equivalent code, it doesn't care.

Actually, you need no `BITS` as the distance is taken modulo 64 (guaranteed in Java, undefined in C).

---

```
public static boolean match(final String pattern, final String text)
```

See my comment on the linked CR concerning `indexOf` and `contains`.

Concerning naming, you're looking for a `pattern` in a `text`, that's fine, but maybe searching a `needle` in a `haystack` would be even clearer.

```
if (pattern == null || text == null || pattern.length() > text.length()) {
    return false;
}
```

Don't allow `null`s. Just throw as every `null` means a problem and the earlier you fail, the better. See [Guava's arguments](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained).

I'd probably go for

```
if (pattern.length() >= text.length()) {
    return pattern.equals(text);
}
```

and simply let it blow on any `null`.

Someone less lazy would add explicit

```
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;

checkNotNull(pattern);
checkNotNull(text);
```

---

```
int[] possibles =
```

I'd call it `result`.

```
int pos = 0;
while ((pos = kr.next()) >= 0) {
```

This should be a `for` loop.

---

> added in a performance test

Benchmarking Java is hard, have a look at [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Comment: Hmmm. The `Integer.rotate*` are new to me. Thanks, but, most of your comments about the prime shift are making the assumption that the hash is an int, but it's a long. The 31-bit shift/rotate is convenient because it means that it wil only start XORing chars at any position after 64 rotations. The modulo 32 you talk about is a misunderstanding?

Comment: @rolfl I completely missed the `long`. Then 31 is fine, but probably not optimal. It takes 64 rotations till you arrive at exactly the same position, but after 2 rotations you arrive very close to it. My modulo 32 should be modulo 64. I'm gonna update my answer now.

Comment: To get 64 steps before characters are overlaid 'in sync' again requires only that the shift be coprime to 64. I.e. any odd number will do. 7 is a good choice for ASCII data but it is best to try a wider range of shifts against a representative test corpus. Rotation is a half-cycle op on modern CPUs, without rotation it's two half-cycle shifts in parallel plus a half/quarter-cycle combining op (+ or ^ or |) but latency can slow things down if it has nowhere to hide (i.e. no convenient latency shadow). Rotation/shift by a variable amount carries a throughput penalty of one cycle.

Comment: That's a combined latency of 2 with throughput 1.75 to 2 for the simulated variable rotation vs. latency 3.5 or thereabouts for MUL with a throughput of 1. IOW, things are not clear cut and the specific circumstances play a big role.

Comment: @DarthGizka Yes, a measurement would be necessary. There are always two `char`s to be processed, and they have to be fetched first, and... well that's about all. Actually, I did some rolling hash benchmarks some time ago.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I only wanted to quantify the difference between the empiric rotation hash and the original multiplicative version, for a reasonably representative modern processor. Just to give an idea of the orders of magnitude involved, or how tiny and fickle the difference actually is.